# Failed to Convert .ipynb to HTML in Jupyter Notebook: nbconvert Error

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, internal-server-error, nbconvert

Having problem while converting .ipynb to html in Jupyter notebook.

I have tried to download a file as html format but it is showing

> 500 : Internal Server Error

The error was:

> nbconvert failed: Document is empty

I am a math student using Python as a tool. I am not very good at terms. I am opening Jupyter notebook from Anaconda navigator.

- I have updated my MacBook to Ventura 13.4
- Jupyter notebook version is 6.5.4.

I don't know if I can see any version of nbconvert or update it.

The file I am trying to convert into html has data visualisation (plots, diagrams etc.) it it.

I don't know if this information will be helpful or not because I can convert some other files but not this one!